# What is a generator of de Rham cohomology?

Tags: differential-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

I met the following definition on a text I'm reading.

Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ be a smooth map between two closed oriented
manifolds of dimension $d$. Then $f$ defines a pullback on de Rham cohomology
$f^* : H^d_{dR}(N,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^d_{dR}(M,\mathbb{R})$. Let $\omega$ be the generator of $H^d_{dR}(N,\mathbb{R})$, then the mapping degree of $f$ is defined to be $\int_M f^* \omega$.

Can someone explain the answers to the following questions?

1. How do you define the generator of $H^d_{dR}(N,\mathbb{R})$? Can we take any $d-form$ as a generator?
2. If $\omega$ is such a generator does it satisfy the condition $\int_N \omega=1$?

Thank you.

Comment: You know that $\dim H^d(N)=1$ so there's and isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $H^d(N)$. Now $1\in \mathbb{R}$ is mapped to something, namely the cohomology class $[\omega]$. This $\omega$ is the generator.

Comment: You can ask $\omega$ to be integrated to $1$. In fact you can ask it to be integrated to any nonzero number.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Is there a natural choice for a generator when the manifold is equipped with an additional structure, let's say a Riemannian metric?

Comment: The generator is called " volume element" or $\sqrt{\det (g_{ij})} dx^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx^n$